# left join query in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, join, left-join

I have added this code in my controller where I am left joining on 2 tables to stored result in lettergroup variable.

```
var lettergroup = (from e in opsdb.Queue2
                   join a in opsdb.QIncidents on e.QID equals a.QID into ps
                   from ad in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new { ad.IncidentID, ad.TaxTypeID, ad.TaxPeriod, ad.StateID, ad.IncidentDate, e.CustomerID, e.DocumentID }).ToList();
```

I get this error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized  value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Please help me out with left join query in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: are you sure error in this peace of code and not elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var lettergroup = (from e in opsdb.Queue2
                   join a in opsdb.QIncidents on e.QID equals a.QID into ps
                   from a in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { IncidentId= a.IncidentID, TaxTypeID=a.TaxTypeID, 
TaxPeriod= a.TaxPeriod, StateID= a.StateID, IncidentDate= a.IncidentDate,
CustomerID=e.CustomerID,DocumentID =e.DocumentID }).ToList();
```